# How fit image contents inside div?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, text-editor, nicedit

In  my details page,I am displaying description from database,which is added by using HTML editor.

```
<div class="text"><?php echo html_entity_decode($details['description']); ?></div>
```

Is it proper way to display HTML content?

My second problem is,when large image coming in description,full image not fitting inside div.I want to fit all my HTML description in to class "text".
How it is possible?
[image]

I am using PHP Codeigniter and Nice Editor.

Comment: `<img src="..." width="300">` this will resize the image width to 300 px for example.

Comment: this is more a css / html question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.text img {
    width: 100%; //Fit the large images.
    min-width: 100%; //Fit the small images.
}
```

Comment: I would recommend `width: auto; max-width: 100%;`  if the OP wants the images to fit, but not fill the div

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way which is compatible with every web browser is to use this (while replacing ## and ## with width and height of image in pixels):

```
<div class="text">
text above image goes here<br>
<img src="whatever.jpg" width=## height=##><br>
text below image goes here
</div>
```